# How to raise a ValidationError AND return a response?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

After checking my form is valid I perform additional validation:

```
def reset_passwd(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = ResetPasswdForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # extract data
            passwd1  = form.cleaned_data['passwd1']
            passwd2  = form.cleaned_data['passwd2']
            # validate passwd
            if passwd1 != passwd2:
                raise forms.ValidationError('passwords are not the same', 'passwd_mismatch')
            # do stuff...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')
    else:
        form = ResetPasswdForm(req.POST)
    return render(req, 'reset_passwd_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Problem is raising a `ValidationError` which is an `Exception` of course breaks execution of the view function so no response is returned!

How is one suppose to return their bound form showing validation errors for validation not performed by `form.is_valid()`?

(The confusing thing is the django documentation say `form.is_valid()` throws `ValidtionError`s if the form is invalid, however it must handel them as debugging it execution continues when `is_valid()` is false.)

Comment: You should check such things in `clean()` method of a form.

Comment: @Rohan thanks, I see now, you could put it an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate such cases, you should use `clean()` method of a form, rather than raising an error in the view.

This is nicely explained at [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the is_valid() method, call the super is_valid() first ( return false if it returns false ), and then handle your error case.

If you use clean() instead you won't benefit for things such as "required=True" in your other fields and will need to check everything manually.
super().clean() just ... does not check for it afaik, and it could give you KeyError when accessing cleaned_data['passwd1'] unless checking it yourself.

```
class MyResetPasswdForm(forms.Form):
    passwd1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    passwd2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)

def is_valid(self):
    valid = super(MyResetPasswdForm).is_valid()
    if not valid:
        return valid
    if self.cleaned_data.get("passwd1") != self.cleaned_data.get("passwd2"):
        # You cannot raise a ValidationError because you are not in the clean() method, so you need to add the error through the add_error method.
        self.add_error("passwd2", ValidationError('passwords are not the same', 'passwd_mismatch')
        # You could also use None instead of "passwd2" if you do not want the error message to be linked to the field.
    if not self.errors:
        return True
    return False
```

This way, you get the pre-set error messages, django handles the fields requirements when you call the super().is_valid().